# python manage.py runserver won't run after git cloning my repo

Tags: python, django

I am having issues running `python manage.py runserver`  after git cloning my project repo, creating a virtual environment and installing all required requirements.

```
(.venv) PS C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107> python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 244, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 225, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 203, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 137, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 576, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 57, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 284, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 260, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 243, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 244, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 225, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 203, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\desktop\project\file-comp-107\.venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Comment: The application requires a PostgreSQL database and it is not available or not properly configured.

Comment: And BTW: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: This was helpful, I now no what to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have an error with your `database` connection. Use and replace the below code snippet with your own credentials in your `settings.py` file. Happy coding

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME',
        'USER': 'YOUR_DATABASE_USERNAME',
        'PASSWORD': 'YOUR_DATABASE_USERNAME',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',

        # Use the below Options when you have a Postgresql server with SSL.
        # 'OPTIONS': {
        #     'sslmode': 'require',
        # }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats, Your answer was highly helpful

Answer (score 0):

As the error returned is `django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`, I assume a environment variable which sets the DB password is missing.